# Concerned about losing commission to new salesperson

Tags: management, salary, sales

I joined my company 2.5 years ago as a sales person coming from a technical background. I have utilised some past existing relationships to bring in additional business and new customers. Until now I was the only salesperson in the company (others had come and go, usually getting fired).

We have a new CEO and they brought in a new VP of Sales. This person is experienced in the field and is someone I am happy to learn from. However they want to bring in a new salesperson (that they already know from a previous job) and have already hinted that they may transition some of the accounts I have developed.

I am aware this happens but am nervous as to how this will impact my commission. I can’t imagine an incoming VP of Sales would alienate an existing – successful – salesperson and give away my potential earnings to someone else.

Is losing income something I should be worried about? What is best practice from a management perspective?

Comment: Hi noblerthanoedipus, welcome to The Workplace! I edited your question to be a little more [on-topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for our site. We don't know your contract or how commission works at your company, so we can't tell you whether your pay will be affected. We *can* give you advice on how to bring up the topic with your manager. If you want to make any more changes to your question, feel free to [edit] it yourself. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your input. I changed the edit a little more. The first question you posed is bang on. For how I approach the situation, I am not worried about how I will bring it up, I just want to know how management would view it. Is this the appropriate stack to ask for that perspective?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a question we can answer. Will the new manager play favorites? Will you lose income? We're not psychic, we can't answer those questions. Presumably the new manager will help open up new markets, and the company (as well as yourself) will only stand to gain from it.

Comment: UPDATE: I left the job. As @paparazzo said below the VP just wanted their guy. I was sidelined, got nothing extra and left within 10 months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be a matter of policy or just what the VP wants to do.

Some times you will get part of the commissions for a period of time.  Like 50% for 12 months.  Some times you get nothing.

If you get nothing have an argument ready.

> It is not fair to give up commissions for account(s) I have built up
>   with nothing in return.

If this is an aggressive VP that just wants his guy then argue is not going to get you very far.

Your non-compete is very critical to how hard you can push. If you cannot move to a competing company for X months you have very little strength. If you can move and are willing to leave and customers may come with you then you can take a hard line but be careful.

I know a girl that built up her district 3 times only to have it taken from her to be put in the worst district.  On the 3rd time she found another job.

Comment: Thank you and yes, I was planning to have that exact argument ready. What would then be fair to ask for? I was thinking a salary raise for the amount I will miss out on is not unreasonable to ask for.

Comment: @noblerthanoedipus Doubt you are going to get a  full salary raise for that amount.  That is not a guaranteed commission and the idea is now you have time to work other accounts.   I think you need to soften your going in position.

Comment: @noblerthanoedipus you may want to update your resume, regardless